# How to verify connection and product ID in react-native-iap

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

Hello I am trying to understand the documentation of the react-native in app purchases but I cannot find any docs that describe how to properly implement the *initConnection* function from the module and get the products that have been already approved by the apple store connect platform?

I would like to know how to connect the react native project to the app store connect and the in app purchase features so that I may verify that it is actually working. Because all of the documents as of now have just been showing to use the function  `RNIap.initConnection()` and to console.log the connection but I keep receiving an undefined in the terminal as I log it.

Whenever I try to `requestSubscription()` I keep getting product ID is not valid as a error and I am not sure as to why ?  I am assuming because I am not properly connected to the platform.

I have made a sandbox account to test the in app purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the middle of doing this as well.  One of the things I found is that I needed to have the Banking and Tax information set up in App Store Connect and validated before I could do much. Until I did that, I couldn't get very far with testing Subscriptions.  Hope that helps.